# JSON overwrite using HashMap JAVA

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I understand there are many stackoverflow question and answer can help to fix this. My Question is not about fixing but writing properly. I need people view and I make better decision.

Here is JSON example :

```
"SearchResult": {
    "usersList": [
        {
            "name": "userId",
            "value": "1009"
        },
        {
            "name": "userName",
            "value": "{userName}"
        },
        {
            "name": "userUrl",
            "value": "{userUrl}"
        }
    ]
}
```

We have test that overwrite this JSON and send as `resultList` to application.

For overwrite we have put value to `HashMap`:

```
public Map<String, String> createUserList(String userName, String userUrl) {
    Map<String, String> putsValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //putsValue.put("{userName}", userName);
    putsValue.put("\\{userName\\}", userName);
    putsValue.put("\\{userUrl\\}", userUrl);
    return putsValue;
}
```

Question is When I used

```
putsValue.put("{userName}", userName);
```

When I try to parse JSON using following code :

```
String jsonTemplate = "fileName.json";
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(new FileReader(jsonTemplate));
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
parsedJson = root.toString();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> putsValue: putsValue.entrySet()) {
    parsedJson = parsedJson
                    .replaceAll(putsValue.getKey(), putsValue.getValue());
}
```

I am getting this error

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{userName}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

How I can find tags like this:

```
putsValue.put("{userName}", userName);
```

And replace value I don't want to do this way

```
putsValue.put("\\{userName\\}", userName);
```

Comment: `putsValue.put("{userName}", userName);` has nothing to do with `PatternSyntaxException`. Not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes right let me update

Comment: `replaceAll` -> read the documentation for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Pattern.quote(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) as next:

```
parsedJson = parsedJson
                .replaceAll(Pattern.quote(putsValue.getKey()), putsValue.getValue());
```

Comment: I have more than 20 value. Is there way I can minimize this efforts because I don't think so if I use Pattern.quote for all put my code review pass.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can do it once when you call replaceAll instead

Answer (score 0):

No need in custom json mapper in your case.
Use Jackson.
You need just to provide getters/setters and annotate fields.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
```

Deserialize json:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Clazz obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Clazz.class);
```

Serialize to json:

```
   class Clazz {
       @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
       ... field declaration;
   }
   String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the regular expression `replaceAll`; just use `replace`.

```
parsedJson = parsedJson.replace(putsValue.getKey(), putsValue.getValue());
```

Comment: I tried doesn't work. Thank you so much. I have huge respect for you.